# How to generate unique names for each epoch's saved model with TensorFlow's Keras API

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I am training model with `fit_generator()` and want to generate unique names for each epoch's saved wights

**Already tried:** see code behind

**Code:**

```py
model_path = '.\checkpoints\cp{}.ckpt'.format(time())
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_path, 
                                                 verbose=1,
                                                  period=2)
```

```py
model.fit_generator(..........,callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

**Expected:** To generate unique checkpoints name
e.g.  epoch_4.ckpt or epoch_5.ckpt
**Actual:** Each time when it saves, overwrites existing checkpoint

Comment: Try feeding the checkpoint path, `'.\checkpoints\cp{}.ckpt'.format(time())` straight to `ModelCheckpoint` instead of saving it in `model_path`. The `model_path` variable will only be evaluated once at runtime, so it will continue overwriting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try adding the epoch variable to the filepath variable

```
filepath = ".\checkpoints\cp-{epoch:02d}.hdf5"
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, verbose=1, period=2)
```

The Keras documentation [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/) already mentions this.

Comment: Happy to help. Kindly accept the answer if it worked.